# Joomla Sparky: Sometimes returning pure CSS to the homepage

Tags: css, joomla

Sometimes, when visiting the homepage of our site, it just returns pure CSS. I'm not sure where this is coming from, and it only happens sometimes. Typically it happens when going to a page through Facebook, but recently it also happens when you directly access the site.

Here's the site in question: https://www.bayfoundation.org/

Has anyone run into this issue before? The site is built using Joomla, and I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. We deal with code here, so you'd have to show some. We're not going to be able to help debug server configurations.

Comment: I do have quite a bit of Joomla experience, and I've never seen this. It's either a code problem or some sort of server config problem, or you've been hacked. You might check your .htaccess file for evidence of hacking, and look at files recently changed.

Comment: @Zachary Asking about Joomla and its extensions is on-topic on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  You might have an easier time of finding a Joomla user with a similar experience by posting there.